# js inheritance and prototype assignment

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

I am learning about JS prototyping and inheritance, I had learned that the right way to do it is by:

```
function A(){}
A.prototype.doSomething=function(){}
function B(){}
B.prototype = new A();
console.log( (new B()) instanceof A);//true
console.log( (new B()) instanceof B);//true
```

As you can see I am setting new instance of A into B
but as you can see it works great with

```
function A(){}
A.prototype.doSomething=function(){}
function B(){}
B.prototype = A.prototype;
console.log( (new B()) instanceof A);//true
console.log( (new B()) instanceof B);//true
```

but here:
http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#76

they claimed that prototype assignment is wrong,I don't understand why?

Comment: try see mdn about [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof), when you assign prototype, in second case, you don't get _B inherit A_ you get _B and A inherit from some other_

Comment: You have a syntax error in 2nd line. Did you mean `A.prototype.doSomething = function(){}`?

Comment: @pawel you are right, I had corrected it, thanks!

Comment: Doing `B.prototype = A.prototype;` you will have `((new B() instanceof A) == true` but also `((new A()) instanceof B) == true`, does as Grundy suggested. The site you posted fail in the instanceof test due `Ninja.prototype = { dance: Person.prototype.dance };` this break the prototype chain.

Comment: it breaks it beacuse 

Ninja.prototype = { dance: Person.prototype.dance };
is reassign the general object into prototype  and overrides the assignement

Answer (score 1):

here is the reason in the first example:

```
console.log( (new B()) instanceof A);//true
```

But

```
console.log( (new A()) instanceof B);//true
```

So this is wrong usage....
The right way is to do it in the next way:

```
function Parent(){}
function Child(){}
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
```